# Removing elements from a DOM copy

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to remove a element from a copy of the main DOM however i cannot get it to work.

Basically i am trying to remove the h2 element from the duplicate DOM and return the modified code in an alert however with whatever i have tried so far i just get the original DOM still.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Test</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" id="CustomScript">

    var Page = document.documentElement;
    var TempPage = document.documentElement;

    TempPage.removeChild("h2"); // Remove Not working
    TempPage.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = ""; // Remove Not working

</script>

<input type="button" value="Get Pages Code" onclick="alert(TempPage.innerHTML)">

</body>
</html>
```

If possible i would rather not use jQuery or YUI etc and just want to use regular Javascript.

Comment: Looks like the problem here is not understanding how [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your question and you are doing them both incorrectly.

1. `TempPage` is the *same* object as `Page`. Assignment to a different variable does not make a copy--it just lets you access the same object via another name.  You need to explicitly create a copy.
2. Your attempts to get the `h2` element are both incorrect.

   1. `removeChild()` won't work because:

      1. It requires a Node object, not a string.
      2. `documentElement` is the `<html>` element, but the `<h2>` element is a child of `<body>`, not `<html>`.
   2. `getElementById()` won't work because your `<h2>` element does not have an id attribute.

How you would do this is:

```
var TempPage = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true); // copy document
var h2 = TempPage.querySelector('h2'); // find h2 element
h2.parentNode.removeChild(h2);  // remove h2 element
```

If `querySelector` is not available, this will be a much more tedious task but still possible using normal DOM manipulation. You really need to [learn about DOM manipulation](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-and-the-dom-series-lesson-1/)

However from your complete code I can't fathom why you would need to clone the page. Just do this:

```
function textContent(node) {
    return node.textContent || node.innerText || '';
}
var h2 = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
var h2Text = textContent(h2);
```

Comment: I had code to extract the `<h2>` too, but then I realised is that he wants the page contents _except_ for the `<h2>`

Answer (score 1):

`TempPage` and `Page` are the *same* element, just with two different variables pointing at it.

Any changes made via one variable will automatically happen to the other.  To treat them differently, one would have to be a clone of the other.  [`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode) may be of use, but is not widely supported.  You will need to make a *deep* copy.

Comment: How can i make TempPage unique? i think i tried var TempPage = Page; but it would not work either.

Comment: I try using var TempPage = node.cloneNode(Page); but it still won't work.

Comment: Your question is unclear - are you wanting to alert the _contents_ of the `<h2>`, or the contents of the rest of the page _excluding_ the `<h2>` ?

Comment: I want to alert the contents of the rest of the page excluding the <h2>. Also h2 was just a basic example for what i wanted to do later after i have this working so there would be more elements removed or modified etc in the duplicate DOM.

Comment: right, so you probably need `TempPage = Page.cloneNode(true);`